# Burninate [apostrophe] and [single-quotes] tags

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I didn't want to take this upon myself without some feedback from the community.  But we have a few lovely little tags that really no one can be an expert in:

[apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apostrophe) and [single-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-quotes)

Many of the questions have to do with string formatting, special characters, escaping which are on-topic but I don't think someone is going to come on the site and specifically look for questions with either tag. I recommend burninating them, what say you apostrophe experts?

Comment: "I" am an 'expert' in `back`, 'forward', and "double" quotes... how can you ***say*** that *no-one* can be?

Comment: Speaking of which, how about the 144: [tag:backticks] ?

Comment: Well @rolfl every user of SO is probably an expert in backticks, right?

Comment: Based on past experience, I was expecting a lot more SQL questions about single quotes.

Comment: Since there is a tag for special characters that could probably cover those questions... Yeah, I don't think those tags are worth much.

Comment: [double-quotes] also ?

Comment: @bluefeet given the number of multi-line code formatted as inline rather than block quote... I find your claim of expertness in backticks for the whole of the SO community dubious.

Comment: I was just about to add the same request before I found this post, can we revive it as I couldn't see any negative comments about this request?

Comment: was also looking at the [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) tag, that has some guidance to not use it, but it's still being used.

Answer (score 10):

These are completely useless tags and should be met with burninated with the fury of a thousand suns.

What prowess denotes a mere dabbler of the apostrophe from the full fledged master?

In the VB world, a ' is your comment character whereas python uses ' as one of the 3 symbols you can use for string containment.

Having these tags is every bit as useful as having a [tag:@] in case people wanted to talk about email. Or pass in username/password in browser FTP sessions. Or something else redonkulous.

Burn it. Burn it with fire. So say we all.

Comment: Aye! Burn them in the fire of righteous wrath!